# python selenium increase value in text field up to x

Tags: python, selenium, user-defined-functions

I am using a input and a selenium webdriver code to fill a specific textfield on a web page.

This is the code:

```
ask_max_price = int(input("Please enter your max price: ")
print("You will buy for max price of", + ask_max_price)
time.sleep(2)

set_max_price = driver.find_element_by_xpath("text field max price")
set_max_price.click()
time.sleep(1)
set_max_price.send_keys(ask_max_price)
```

So this is clicking into the text field "max price" and enters the number, that was entered by the user with the input. After that I click on a search button, and it loads the "search results" page on the web page.

After, I let python click on a "back button" to get back to the page where I have entered the number in the text field.

Now to my problem: 
There is a second text field called "min price" on the web page. This field must also get filled and it must raise in value every time after I click on the "back button" (to refresh the chrome cache) before I search again. Otherwise I would always get the same search result as with the initial search.

So for clarification it looks like this:

Before first search:
Text field min price:
Text field max price: ask_max_price

I need a code, that enters an initial value of "200" to the min price field (after the first search) and adds "+50" everytime I come back to this page.

So for example:

1. Search:
   Text field min price: 0
   Text field max price: 750

I search and go back.

2. Search:
   Text field min price: 200
   Text field max price: 750

I search and go back.

3. Search: 
   Text field min price: 250
   Text field max price: 750

The min price should raise until it reaches what has been entered by the user for "ask_max_price". Then it should be set back to 0 again and repeat.

Since I am new to programming, I cant find a solution for this issue myself.

I hope I could explain clear enough what I need. Since upload of screenshots is not allowed, I hope my example is clear.

Could anyone please help me how I could code something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably use a `while` loop to do this, so you can start execution with `min` price equal to 200, and increment by 50 each loop through.

I also noticed you are not utilizing any kind of targeted explicit waits (besides `sleep()`), which will introduce issues in your code if you are switching back and forth between pages. Introducing `WebDriverWait` will mediate this problem.

Because you have not provided any HTML and cannot provide screenshots, I can only provide a rough solution of how this would look:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
# include the above to use WebDriverWait

# declare constant increment value
increment_value = 50

# declare initial min price value
current_min_value = 200

# declare max value to keep track of
max_value = 750

# execute loop until current_value equals or exceeds max_value
while current_min_value <= max_value:

    # wait for min price input to appear
    min_price_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "min price input field")))

    # enter current_value for min price -- this starts at 200
    min_price_element.send_keys(current_min_value)

    # wait for max price to appear
    max_price_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "max price input field")))

    # enter max price value
    max_price_element.send_keys(max_value)

    # click search
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("search").click()

    # todo: what actions do you perform on search results page? perform them here, before clicking back.

    # click back
    driver.back()

    # increment current_min_value by 50 for next loop iteration
    current_min_value = current_min_value + increment_value
```

This program starts with 3 values -- `increment_value` which is 50, the amount to increment `current_min_value` by. `current_min_value`, which starts at 200 -- the initial price to enter into min. value. And, `max_value`, which is 750, the number to be entered in max price field each time.

This `while` loop executes until `current_min_value` exceeds `max_value`. It will enter the min. and max prices in the respective fields -- `[200, 750]`, `[250, 750]`, `[300, 750]`,  etc.

After each price is entered, we `click()` on Search. After you click search, you can scrape the page or whatever you intend to do on the search results page.

Then, we call `driver.back()` to return to the previous page, and repeat the process with the `+50` incremented value of min. price.